# Unable to style ng-component

Tags: angular

I have a component with a router outlet.

```
<div class="main">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Inside I am routing to another component, which results in markup rendered like this:

```
<div class="main">
  <router-outlet _ngcontent-c0=""></router-outlet>
  <ng-component class="ng-star-inserted">
    <my-component>...</my-compoenent>
  </ng-component>
</div>
```

The issue is that the `<ng-component>` element does not span full width. I need it to be `width: 100%;`. I *don't want to use ViewEncapsulation.None* in the parent component, because I want the styles isolated.

I also don't want to add a global style for ng-component because this will have lots of side effects throughout my app that I don't want.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is this `ng-component`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to use the `:host` selector in my-component.scss:

```
:host {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can globally target the DOM element without having side effects.

```
div.main > ng-component {
    width: 100%;
}
```